# Call a swift method to perform segue from objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm relatively new to iOS developing and I am facing an issue, I'd like to call a Swift method performing a segue from Objective C

Here is my Swift method :

```
@objc func callReceived() {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goto_incomingcall", sender: self)
}
```

I am calling it from Objective C this way :

```
ViewController *controller = [ViewController new];
[controller callReceived];
```

With the new method being so :

```
func `new`() -> ViewController {
    return ViewController()
}
```

If I am guessing right, the problem I am facing is that I am initializing a new instance of my class ViewController then calling my method to perform the segue, and as it is not the current instance of the `ViewController` class, performing the segue from another instance of the class makes the whole program crashes with a `signal SIGABRT`

What would be the correct way for doing it?

Regards.

Comment: Are you using storyboards? because if you are, initializing a new instance and call a method in it to perform a segue is not the right approach, instead you need to the ViewController from storyboard by its id and call the method.

Comment: No, I am not using the storyboard, context is a VoIP app, upon receiving a call I'd like to segue to a new ViewController to either accept or deny the incoming call, VoIP part is done in Objective C, the rest is in Swift

Comment: Well, you can't work with segues if you are not using storyboard(s).

Comment: I've used the storyboard to set up the project but haven't used it since

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should import that swift class file in objective c file .
After  `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goto_incomingcall", sender: self)` you should use - **Prepare for segue** method for data transfer .
Create a reference of that class like this -

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goto_incomingcall"]){
        Vc = (ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        Vc.MethodSelected();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't seem to work any better, maybe my Swift 3 implementation of it is wrong? Isn't the `prepapreForSegue` method used for passing data between ViewControllers?

Comment: override  func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

Comment: Well in fact it doesn't work because i'm not in the original instance of `ViewController` but in another one allocated in my Objective C function